# PHP isn't executing ps command (possible permission issue?)

Tags: php, ps

I have a small script I tested on the command line using `php test.php`.

## **test.php**

```
<?php
    exec('ps -acux | grep test', $testvar);
    print_r($testvar);
?>
```

This works fine. I am able to run the script and get the desired result. However, when I add the code to a file being run by my PHP server, the result is empty.

My OS is `FreeBSD`. Looking at the [man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ps&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.2-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html) for `ps` the only restriction I see is on the `-a` option. It states:

> If the security.bsd.see_other_uids sysctl is set to zero, this option
> is honored only if the UID of the user is 0.

My security.bsd.see_other_uids is set to 1.

```
$ sysctl security.bsd.see_other_uids
security.bsd.see_other_uids: 1
```

The only thing I can think of is that the command is being run by my user when I run it via the command line whereas when run by PHP, it's being run by `www`. I'm not seeing anything in the manual of `ps` that indicates `www` shouldn't be able to run the command.

Comment: What about `grep test`? Are you certain it will match something?

Comment: @ZoliSzabó I modified the grep, it's not actually test, but it's just another single word. I indicated in the OP that it does return the desired result. When run via the command line it returns 10 processes. When run via the PHP process it returns 0.

Comment: The `ps` command (without -a) will return processes run by the current account. Since from command line is one account and from PHP is another (`www`), are you really sure `grep` should still match something? Have you tried it without `grep`, just `ps`?

Comment: The third argument for `exec` is the result code. Dump its value too...

Comment: @ZoliSzabó The processes are not from either account. When run as a regular user, without the `-a` it would return 0. I need the `-a` to return all processes. I am absolutely certain. I am running the same code one via `php test.php` which returns 10 processes and one via the actual PHP server which returns 0. If I remove the `-a` they both return 0. The result code is 0 when run via `test.php` and 1 when ran by the server.

Comment: Exit code 1 is clearly a signal of error. Try redirecting `stderr` to `stdout` using: `exec('ps -acux | grep test 2>&1', $testvar);` This should give you back the human-readable error message.

Comment: @ZoliSzabó you would think... but it didn't print an error. It just printed out the list of processes. So for some reason it's printing out the list of processes to `stderr` when using the `pipe`. If I run it just `ps -acux` it runs fine. When I add the `pipe` with the `grep`, it prints the processes to `stderr` with no error message.

Comment: (If you haven't tried) skip `grep` and leave the output redirection. Maybe there is some error grep is filtering out...

Comment: @ZoliSzabó Nope, without grep it runs fine without the 2>&1. With the 2>&1 and no grep there's no additional error message (t also returns a 0 for the result). Looks like a bug with exec and the pipe. If you'd like to submit the 2>&1 as an answer I can accept that as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments you need to redirect `stderr` to `stdout`. This is achieved by `2>&1` to the end of your command. So an example of the `PHP exec()` is as follows:

```
exec('ps -acux | grep test 2>&1', $testvar);
```

This allows you to see potential errors. In my case there was no error and likely a bug of some sorts. However this is useful in all cases where you execute a command. If any error were to occur you can retrieve it to see what is happening with your command.